# Styles.xml no more in Android Studio version 4.1

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm creating a new project and noticed that styles.xml is no longer generated in Android Studio version 4.1. The only present there is themes.xml which has similar code with styles.xml.
Does themes.xml replaced styles.xml? And if so, can I still manually create styles.xml without producing error? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does themes.xml replaced styles.xml?

In terms of what the new-project wizard creates, yes. The filenames in `res/values/` do not matter — what matters are the names (and values) of the resources defined in those files.

> And if so, can I still manually create styles.xml without producing error?

Yes.

Comment: I found out that the name of the file doesn't matter by accident. It turned out that you can name the file anything you want as long as you reference the items inside correctly.