# No styles.xml file when I created a new project

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just started developing android applications with Android Studio, I've watched couple of tutorial videos so I'm not very good at it, one of the tutorial videos used a file called `styles.xml` which is in `res/values`, but when I went to that folder, I didn't find the `styles.xml` file, I thought it may have glitched and not generated itself once I created my project, can somebody please help me?

Comment: You can create styles.xml file in res/values folder yourself.

Comment: But why didn't it get generated by itself?

Comment: How to create project in android studio? It seems to select No Activity. Please select other template in select project template.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64971556/styles-xml-no-more-in-android-studio-version-4-1. It now generates "themes.xml".

Answer (score 1):

While creating the project select on the page SELECT A PROJECT TEMPLATE, Select "Empty Activity". It will create style.xml with the project.
As below:

[image]

If we create project with "No Activity" it doesn't generate any style file and activity.

[image]

Comment: That's what I did, I selected "Empty Activity" when I created my projects but the file wasn't there.

Answer (score 1):

In Latest Android Studio versions, it creates **themes.xml** rather than styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rebuild project. Build -> Rebuild Project. If that does not help, try to make a new project.

Comment: I tried rebuilding, it didn't work, I also tried to create a new project but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create styles.xml file in res/values folder yourself as following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style
        name="style_name"
        parent="@[package:]style/style_to_inherit">
        <item
            name="[package:]style_property_name"
            >style_value</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

If you want to know more detail, Please look this url.
[https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource)

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Flamingo version it creates themes folder(contains themes.xml & themes.xml(night)) instead of style.xml